# Label error in js

Tags: javascript, label

I wanted to build a timer picker scrip from JS pure. 
But I have been this error:

*unexpected ':'     loop1*

**Html:**

```
<select id="hour1">
<option>1</option>
</select>
<select id="hour2"></select>
<select id="minute1"></select>
<select id="minute2"></select>
<select id="period"></select>
<select id="period"></select>
```

**js:**

```
var hour1 = document.getElementById("hour1"),
       hour2 = document.getElementById("hour2"),
       minute1 = document.getElementById("minute1"),
       minute2 = document.getElemetById("minute2"),
       period = document.getElementById("period"),
       hourCase1 = 0,
       hourCase2 = 0,
       minuteCase1 = 0,
       minuteCase2 = 0;
     Loop1: 
     for (;;) {
         Loop2:
         for (;hourCase2 <= 9;) {
               hour1.innerHTML += "<option>" +   hourCase1 + hourCase2 + "</option>";
               hourCase2 += 1;
          }
         hourCase1 += 1;
        if (hourCase1 == 1 && hourCase2 == 2) {
               break Loop1;
      }
}
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're coming from a language that isn't javascript! I would read a little about the [for loop syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).

You don't need to declare counter variables prior to the loop (they can be declared at the start of the loop). Like so
    `for(var i=0; i < 10; i++){}`

Additionally, the `break` statement will clear you from a loop you are in, [you don't need to specify the loop's name](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp)

Long story short, you need to specify the start and end indexes of the loop, as well as how it should increment.